# Can't write `use std::{fs::self, io::self}` due to multiple uses of `self`

Tags: rust

**Code**

```
use std::{
    fs::self,
    io::self,
};

fn rmdir(path: impl AsRef<std::path::Path>) -> io::Result<()> {
    fs::remove_dir(path)
}
```

**Error**

```
error[E0430]: `self` import can only appear once in an import list
 --> src/lib.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     fs::self,
  |     ^^^^^^^^ can only appear once in an import list
3 |     io::self,
  |     -------- another `self` import appears here
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3c2c2a3f38b512d668240e6de9412cea))

Why can't I write `module::self` with two different modules? I thought I might `use` modules with `::self` to make it clear they're modules, not functions.

If I add curly brace it's allowed:

```
use std::{
    fs::{self},
    io::{self},
};
```

Is there a good reason for this, or is it a compiler bug/language design flaw?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you'd expect to use `use std::io::{self, BufReader}` to mean import `std::io` and `std::io::BufReader`.

```
use std::{ fs::self, io::self };
```

is just

```
use std::{ fs, io };
```

`E0430` is a check for two `self`s in the same `{}` scope. 
This makes something like

```
use something::{self, self};
```

illegal.
When you put each `::self` within its own scope, it's legal.